# How to check if two objects touch each other in python tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, canvas, tkinter, collision

I'm trying to create a function that tells me if two canvas objects(in my code, rec and block) touch each other in Tkinter. I tried to do so with the information of their coordinates but it doesn't seem to work. Can you please help me?

The function will be used in snake which I'm creating in the code below, so don't ask my why the code is so long.

The function is in the line 119, same_poz

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import random
import threading

root = Tk()
root.title('Snake')
x, y = 484, 484
recX, recY = x // 2, y // 2
recW, recH = recX + 22, recY + 22
randoms = []
for i in range(484):
    if i % 11 == 0:
        randoms.append(i)
blockX, blockY = random.choice(randoms), random.choice(randoms)
blockW, blockH = blockX + 22, blockY + 22
c = Canvas(root, bg='black', width=x, height=y)
c.pack()



class Snake(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, c, x, y, recX, recY, recW, recH, blockX, blockY, blockW, blockH):
        super(Snake, self).__init__()
        self.c = c
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.recX = recX
        self.recY = recY
        self.recW = recW
        self.recH = recH
        self.blockW = blockW
        self.blockH = blockH
        self.rec = c.create_rectangle(recX, recY, recW, recH, fill='red', outline='white')
        self.blockX = blockX
        self.blockY = blockY
        self.block = c.create_rectangle(blockX, blockY, blockW, blockH, fill='green', 
        outline='white')
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.moving = False

    def movingright(self):
        self.moving_right = True
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.moving = True
        c.move(self.rec, 11, 0)
        self.after4 = root.after(150, self.movingright)

    def movingleft(self):
        self.moving_left = True
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.moving = True
        c.move(self.rec, -11, 0)
        self.after3 = root.after(150, self.movingleft)

    def movingup(self):
        self.moving_up = True
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving = True
        c.move(self.rec, 0, -11)
        self.after = root.after(150, self.movingup)

    def movingdown(self):
        self.moving_down = True
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.moving = True
        c.move(self.rec, 0, 11)
        self.after2 = root.after(150, self.movingdown)

    def stop(self):
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.moving = False

        try:
            root.after_cancel(self.after)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        try:
            root.after_cancel(self.after2)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        try:
            root.after_cancel(self.after3)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        try:
            root.after_cancel(self.after4)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    def move(self, n):
        if n.keysym == 'Up':
            self.stop()
            self.movingup()
        if n.keysym == 'Down':
            self.stop()
            self.movingdown()
        if n.keysym == 'Right':
            self.stop()
            self.movingright()
        if n.keysym == 'Left':
            self.stop()
            self.movingleft()

    def same_poz(self):
        if self.blockY == self.recY:
            self.helpY = random.randint(10, self.y - self.blockY)
            self.c.move(self.block, 0, self.helpY)
        if self.blockX == self.recY:
            self.helpX = random.randint(10, self.x - self.blockX)
            self.c.move(self.block, 0, self.helpX)
        if self.blockW == self.recW:
            self.helpW = random.randint(10, self.x - self.blockW)
            self.c.move(self.block, 0, self.helpW)
        if self.blockH == self.recH:
            self.helpH = random.randint(10, self.y - self.blockH)
            self.c.move(self.block, 0, helpH)



cube = Snake(c, x, y, recX, recY, recW, recH, blockX, blockY, blockW, blockH)
cube.start()




cube.c.bind_all('<Key>', cube.move, cube.stop)
cube.c.bind_all('<Key>', cube.moving_left, cube.moving_right)
cube.c.bind_all('<Key', cube.moving_up, cube.moving_down)
cube.c.bind(cube.same_poz)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are way too many problems with your code, with what you provided. I do not know why you are programming using Tkinter when you are still lacking the basics of Python. (Don't mean to sound harsh)

1. I do not know why you decided to inherit from `threading.Thread` when
   you do not have any use for anything `Thread` provides in that
   class.
2. Way too many instance parameters which you have no use for at all, and too many instance parameters that you have to change every single time.
3. Not using `elif` and instead using `if` constantly.
4. If you are using a thread to handle Tkinter changes outside of mainloop, there is no need to use `.after` since it basically does that.
5. Tkinter has dedicated bindings for every single key, including combinations of keys. There is no need to catch every single key event.
6. Use `if __name__ == '__main__':` if you are working with a single script, for testing it.
7. Some reading material on Tkinter - http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

Here is a minimal rework of the code, that is working.

```
import time
import random
import threading
from tkinter import *

MOVINGUP = 'u'
MOVINGDOWN = 'd'
MOVINGLEFT = 'l'
MOVINGRIGHT = 'r'
NOTMOVING = '0'


class Snake:
    def __init__(self, root, recX, recY, recW, recH, blockX, blockY, blockW, blockH):
        self.root = root

        self.c = Canvas(root, bg='black', width=x, height=y)
        self.c.pack()

        self.rec = self.c.create_rectangle(recX, recY, recW, recH, fill='red', outline='white')
        self.block = self.c.create_rectangle(blockX, blockY, blockW, blockH, fill='green', outline='white')

        self.direction = NOTMOVING

        self.root.bind('<Up>', lambda e: self.moveset(MOVINGUP))
        self.root.bind('<Down>', lambda e: self.moveset(MOVINGDOWN))
        self.root.bind('<Left>', lambda e: self.moveset(MOVINGLEFT))
        self.root.bind('<Right>', lambda e: self.moveset(MOVINGRIGHT))

    def moveset(self, direction):
        self.direction = direction

    def movement(self):
        if self.direction == MOVINGUP:
            self.c.move(self.rec, 0, -11)
        elif self.direction == MOVINGDOWN:
            self.c.move(self.rec, 0, 11)
        elif self.direction == MOVINGLEFT:
            self.c.move(self.rec, -11, 0)
        elif self.direction == MOVINGRIGHT:
            self.c.move(self.rec, 11, 0)
        self.same_poz()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.15)
            self.movement()

    def same_poz(self):
        # Snake (x0, y0, x1, y1)
        snakepos = self.c.bbox(self.rec)
        # Food block (x0, y0, x1, y1)
        food = self.c.bbox(self.block)
        # If direction matters, if not then possible to only use self.hit in a single condition.
        if self.direction == MOVINGRIGHT and self.hit(snakepos, food):
            print('Caught the food moving right.')
        elif self.direction == MOVINGLEFT and self.hit(snakepos, food):
            print('Caught the food moving left.')
        elif self.direction == MOVINGUP and self.hit(snakepos, food):
            print('Caught the food moving up.')
        elif self.direction == MOVINGDOWN and self.hit(snakepos, food):
            print('Caught the food moving down.')

    def hit(self, snakepos, food):
        """
            Recieves coordinates of food block and snake block and returns if they collide.
        :param snakepos: Tuple containing (x0, y0, x1, y1) of the snake.
        :param food: Tuple containing (x0, y0, x1, y1) of the food block.
        :return: Boolean whether they collide
        """
        snakex = (snakepos[0], snakepos[2])
        snakey = (snakepos[1], snakepos[3])
        foodx = (food[0], food[2])
        foody = (food[1], food[3])
        # Returns True if any of the snake x cooridnates are between the food x coordinates, or both x coordinates match.
        if any((foodx[0] < xcoord < foodx[1] for xcoord in snakex)) or foodx == snakex:
            # Returns True if any of the snake y cooridnates are between the food y coordinates, or both y coordinates match.
            return any((foody[0] < ycoord < foody[1] for ycoord in snakey)) or foody == snakey
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Snake')
    x, y = 484, 484
    recX, recY = x // 2, y // 2
    recW, recH = recX + 22, recY + 22
    randoms = []
    for i in range(484):
        if i % 11 == 0:
            randoms.append(i)
    blockX, blockY = random.choice(randoms), random.choice(randoms)
    blockW, blockH = blockX + 22, blockY + 22


    snake = Snake(root, recX, recY, recW, recH, blockX, blockY, blockW, blockH)
    threading.Thread(target=snake.run, daemon=True).start()

    root.mainloop()
```