# SyntaxError near any() command tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, any

Good Evening,

I am trying to make a simple game in python3 tkinter, similar to the snake game, but I am having problems checking if the blue block is touching the "apple" (red block).
I tried to follow the example from [How to check if two objects touch each other in python tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474061/how-to-check-if-two-objects-touch-each-other-in-python-tkinter) with the `hit()` function, but python is returning:

```
line 51
    if any((int(canvas.coords(apple)[0]) < xcoord < (int(canvas.coords(apple)[0]) + 15) for xcoord in (int(canvas.coords(bug)[0]), int(canvas.coords(bug)[0]) + 15) or canvas.coords(apple)[0] == canvas.coords(bug)[0]:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help me with checking if the two blocks are overlapping?

Problematic code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
from threading import *
from random import randint
from math import floor
from os import system, _exit
win = Tk()
threadKill = False
moveing = None
direction = None
score = 0
win.geometry("{}x{}".format(win.winfo_screenwidth(), win.winfo_screenheight()))
win.configure(bg='black')
canvas = Canvas(win, width=win.winfo_screenwidth(), height=win.winfo_screenheight(), bg='black')

bug = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 15, 15,
    outline="blue", fill="blue")
canvas.pack()
apple = canvas.create_rectangle(225, 225, 240, 240,
    outline='red', fill='red')
def new_apple():
  global canvas
  global apple

  xCoord = randint(0, win.winfo_screenwidth() - 15)
  yCoord = randint(0, win.winfo_screenheight() - 15 )
  canvas.coords(apple, xCoord, yCoord, xCoord + 15, yCoord + 15)

def new_block():
  global canvas
  global apple
  while True:
    sleep(2.5)
    xCoord = randint(0, win.winfo_screenwidth() - 15)
    yCoord = randint(0, win.winfo_screenheight() - 15 )
    canvas.create_rectangle(xCoord, yCoord, xCoord + 15, yCoord + 15, outline='green', fill='green')
    if exiting:
      break

#blocksC = Thread(target=new_block).start()

exiting = False
def check_eat():
  global exiting
  global apple
  global bug
  global score
  while True:

    if any((int(canvas.coords(apple)[0]) < xcoord < (int(canvas.coords(apple)[0]) + 15) for xcoord in (int(canvas.coords(bug)[0]), int(canvas.coords(bug)[0]) + 15) or canvas.coords(apple)[0] == canvas.coords(bug)[0]:            # <---- Problems
      if any((canvas.coords(apple)[1] < ycoord < (canvas.coords(apple)[1] + 15) for ycoord in (canvas.coords(bug)[1], canvas.coords(bug)[1] + 15) or canvas.coord(apple)[1] == canvas.coords(bug)[1]:           # <---- Problems
        score += 1
        new_apple()
    sleep(0.002)
    if exiting:
      break
checkE = Thread(target=check_eat).start()
def moveRight():
  canvas.move(bug, 1, 0)
  win.update()
def goRight(e=None):
  global threadKill
  global direction
  while True:
    moveRight()
    sleep(0.004)
    if threadKill and direction != "right":
      threadKill = False
      break
def rightKey(E):
  global moveing
  global threadKill
  global direction
#  new_apple()
  if direction != "right":
    direction = "right"
    threadKill = True
    moveing = Thread(target=goRight).start()
def moveLeft():
  canvas.move(bug, -1, 0)
  win.update()
def goLeft(e=None):
  global threadKill
  global direction
  while True:
    moveLeft()
    sleep(0.004)
    if threadKill and direction != "left":
      threadKill = False
      break
def leftKey(E):
  global moveing
  global threadKill
  global direction
  if direction != "left":
    direction = "left"
    threadKill = True
    moveing = Thread(target=goLeft).start()
def moveUp():
  canvas.move(bug, 0, -1)
  win.update()
def goUp(e=None):
  global threadKill
  global diretion
  while True:
    moveUp()
    sleep(0.004)
    if threadKill and direction != "up":
      threadKill = False
      break
def upKey(E):
  global moveing
  global threadKill
  global direction
  if direction != "up":
    direction = "up"
    threadKill = True
    moveing = Thread(target=goUp).start()

def moveDown():
  canvas.move(bug, 0, 1)
  win.update()
def goDown(e=None):
  global threadKill
  global diretion
  while True:
    moveDown()
    sleep(0.004)
    if threadKill and direction != "down":
      threadKill = False
      break
def downKey(E):
  global moveing
  global threadKill
  global direction
  if direction != "down":
    direction = "down"
    threadKill = True
    moveing = Thread(target=goDown).start()
def stopBug(E):
  global threadKill
  threadKill = True
def end(E=None):
  global reason
  reason = "b"
  win.destroy()
  system(f"/opt/snnnn/score.py {score} {reason} &")
  #Thread(target=system, args=("/opt/snnnn/score.py", str(score), reason, "&"))
exiting = True

win.bind('<Right>', rightKey)
win.bind('<Left>', leftKey)
win.bind('<Escape>', end)
win.bind('<Up>', upKey)
win.bind('<Down>', downKey)
win.bind('<space>', stopBug)
win.mainloop()
```

Any other suggestions on the code would be helpful, too, as well as any other way to check if the squares are overlapping.

Comment: At the very least, you're missing a close parenthesis at the end of the condition, to match the one opened by `any(`.  If the editor you're using can't show you matching parentheses, brackets, etc., then throw it away and get one that's actually suitable for programming.

Comment: I'm using vim, I've just been self-learning, and one of my bad habits is ignoring the matching parentheses "helper". sorry I can't find the right word. Thanks though, that helped!